# How to go back page or back fragment from the fragment in android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

I am using a drawer layout which contains many fragments and when I pressed back button from a specific fragment it directly goes out of the application. I've sees many suggestions like onBackpress() method. Following is my code.. I can't understand where to implement this code and howto. Would any one help me out?

```
private void selectItemFragment(int position){

    Fragment fragment = null;
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch(position) {
        default:
        case 0:
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Profile Fragment 1"+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new UploadQuestionFragment();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fragment 2 "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new DefaultFragment();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fragment 3"+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new GetAllAnswerFragment();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"All Answer Fragment 4 "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new AllQuestionFragment();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fragment 5 "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = null;
            break;
    }

    if(fragment !=null){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(titles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to backstack and pop from backstack in order to achieve it

To add to backstack use

```
public void showFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_frame, fragment);
        mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
        setActionBarTitle(title);
        if (backStateName == DashBoardFragment.class.getSimpleName()) {
            clearBackStack();
        }
    }
}
```

To pop from backstack use

```
private void popFragments(int backStackCount) {
    String fragmentTag = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(
            backStackCount - 1).getName();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fragmentTag)) {
        Fragment currentFragment = mFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.container_frame);
        if (currentFragment != null) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mFragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@opu ...

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

use add() method instead of replace() method

> note- for first time call of fragment use replace() method otherwise
>   use add() method

add() method , also addBackStack() method to stack the fragment one to another

[image: fragment stack using backstack]

hence use

```
//for first fragment
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.main_activity_content_frame, new RestaurantsListFragment(), "fragment" + i)
            //.addToBackStack("fragment" + (i++))
            .commit();

// for other fragment
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.main_activity_content_frame, new RestaurantsListFragment(), "fragment" + i)
            .addToBackStack("fragment" + (i++))
            .commit();


// on back press
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    Log.e("POP FRAGMENT STACK", "Count ="+count);
    if(count==0){
        showExitDialog();
    }else{
        Log.e("POP FRAGMENT STACK", "Fragment Info =" + getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(count - 1).getTag());
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```